# Puppeteer Not Finding Element iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, element, puppeteer, selector

A form is embedded within an iframe. I am trying to use puppeteer to fill out the form. I can select most of the fields in the form but cannot select the submit button.

```
await page.waitForSelector("iframe");
const iframeElement = await page.$('iframe'); 
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForSelector('#input_4'); //picks up the appropriate element
await frame.waitForSelector('button#input_2.form-submit-button.submit-button.jf-form-buttons.jsTest-submitField');//does not pick up the element
```

I have attached a link to the screenshot of the DOM showing where the button is in reference to the iframe.

Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aoKK.jpg)

Comment: Can you upload the outer HTML of the element in code format, rather than in a screenshot? Like that we are able to mock it and test it against your script. Thanks!

Comment: <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button submit-button jf-form-buttons jsTest-submitField" data-component="button" data-content="">
              Submit
            </button>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the selector incorrectly.

❌ **Wrong usage:**

Do not include tag name, id and all CSS classes without any separator between them, especially do not use them at the same time if they are all describing the very same element.

```js
await frame.waitForSelector(button#input_2.form-submit-button.submit-button.jf-form-buttons.jsTest-submitField);
```

(Or you can separate them by commas like: `#input_2, .form-submit-button, .submit-button, .jf-form-buttons, .jsTest-submitField`. But it is very rare you need to go this way.)

✅ **Correct usage:**

You are good with the `id`, it identifies inside `frame` the element you are looking for.

```js
await frame.waitForSelector('#input_2');
```

---

Did you know? If you right click on an element in Chrome DevTools "Elements" tab and you select "Copy": you are able to copy the exact selector or xpath of an element. After that you can switch to the "Console" tab and with the Chrome api you are able to test the selector's content, so you can prepare it for your puppeteer script. E.g.: `$('#input_2').textContent` should show the text of the button that you've expected to click on, otherwise you need to change on the access, or you need to check if there are more elments with the same selector etc. This may helps you to find more appropriate selectors.